# How to replace K-values of list by skipping 9 from startend

Tags: python, list

I have a number lets make it a list s = [1,6,**9**,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]

and I have  k = 4

What I want is to replace 4-values of list s with number 9 which dont have number 9.

means at position 2 ,we have 9,so skip that and replace next one.

Output should be like: [**9,9**,9,**9,9**,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]

With this code I am unable to skip 9's in it:

```
x= [1,6,9,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]
k = 4
def elements_replaced(lst, new_element, indices):
    return [new_element if i in indices else e for i, e in enumerate(lst)]

output = elements_replaced(x,9,range(k))
print output
```

Comment: Does it have to be in the order you have shown?

Comment: @leaf Yes. need to replace or touch only k-values. so replacing first two and skipping third as it has 9 then replace next two. Overall 4 replaces

Comment: why `4,1,9,0,0,` is not changed?

Comment: replace `range(k)` with `range(k+1)`

Comment: @Prajwal : because value of k is 4 and only 4 values can be replace from start.

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
>>> s = [1,6,9,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]
>>> k = 4
>>> for index,number in enumerate(s):
       if k > 0:
          if number != 9:
            s[index] = 9
            k = k-1
       else :
          break    

>>> s
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: I think your answer has redundant iterations in the `for` loop. By adding an `else: break` for `if k > 0:`, this can be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1,6,9,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]
k = 4
a = 0
while k and a < len(x):
    if x[a] != 9:
        x[a] = 9
        k -= 1
    a += 1
```

Comment: You probably also want to check that `a < len(x)`.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list comprehensions. This will get inefficient if your input list is large relative to the number of nines.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

s = [1,6,9,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]

nines = chain([9] * 4, repeat(None))
result = [x if x == 9 else next(nines) or x for x in s]

print(result)
# [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 7, 3, 6, 8, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: You should really use x == 9. It is an implementation detail that small `int`s are equivalent by identity.

Comment: Fair point, although one feels too tempted to get away with such things sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

```
x= [1,6,9,2,3,2,7,3,6,8,4,1,9,0,0,3,6,8]
k = 4
def elements_replaced(lst, new_element, indices):
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        if index in indices and value != new_element:
            lst[index] = new_element
    return lst



output = elements_replaced(x,9,range(k+1))
print (output)
```